# Nuxt application with amazon-cognito-identity-js package gives error fetch is not defined

Tags: amazon-cognito, nuxt.js

I included amazon-cognito-identity-js package in nuxt application and I want to use the sign in method/sign up methods which are provided by this package.

But I am getting following error

fetch is not defined

I installed node-fetch and modified node_module/amazon-cognito-identity-js/Clinet.js as below

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

that solves my prob but I dont want to modify node package.

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js):

> Note: This library uses the Fetch API. For older browsers or in
>   Node.js, you may need to include a polyfill. For example.
>
> ```
> global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
> var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
> ```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I gone through document. But not sure where I need to put this code ?

Comment: No. I am directly using import on nuxt page.

Comment: import is just a replacement for require

Answer (score 0):

I added following code.

```
import { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUserAttribute } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

That solved my problem.