# type error for fetch while using aws-cognito-identity-js

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am building an serverless a app using the `serverless framework` and  `typescript` and using aws cognito for user authentication. 
When I am using the application in `local serverless environment` everything works.
I can sign up a user and also sign the user in to recieve `jwt token`

But when I deploy the code to aws it gives me 
`"message": "fetch is not a function",`

So i go through different github issues / stack overflow and see that everyone suggests the similar solution by adding global.fetch 
Similar solution in this post -> [Nuxt application with amazon-cognito-identity-js package gives error fetch is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540633/nuxt-application-with-amazon-cognito-identity-js-package-gives-error-fetch-is-no)

```
global.fetch = require('node-fetch')
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
```

so I added the above and did an npm install of node-fetch and pushed the code 
but then the problem is different, which is  that since  I am using typescript i can't use `global.fetch`

So i find different ways to change that in local

```
Way 1 
const globalAny:any = global;
globalAny.fetch = require('node-fetch');

Way 2
(global as any).fetch = require('node-fetch');

Way 3 -> Written at the end of this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433783/referenceerror-fetch-is-not-defined
```

And when I run it in both ways in local and also in AWS LAMDA it fails with the same error

`TypeError: fetch is not a function`

So I am out of options and looking if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer versions of node fetch is having issues with webpack that you can find about in this thread. https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/450

Downgrade to `node-fetch@1.7.3` to get your cognito working.

Answer (score 0):

if webpack is used in the project, global.fetch won't work. Add following library in app root level.( recommended for serverless-webpack / any other web pack for lambda codestart )

```
require('cross-fetch/polyfill');
```